Unable to make Github API call due to CORS error in my Next App
I'm working on next js react (ts) app and do I need a server to make github api request as I have added below in my next.config.mjs.
My app only requires call to GitHub api to fetch content of file of public repo.
const nextConfig = {
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/:path*",
                headers: [
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

Below is my code for call
 useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCode = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/Kanav-Arora/DSA-Guide/contents/Binary Search/binary_search.cpp`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${github_api}`,
                },
                method: 'get',
                mode: 'cors',
            });
            console.log(response);
        }
        fetchCode();
    }, [cpp])

Below error is returned
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/Kanav-Arora/DSA-Guide/contents/Binary%20Search/binary_search.cpp', redirected: false, status: 401, ok: false, …}
I have tried adding cors configuration and I expect that Github api should work. Its working perfectly in postman but not in development environment.

Move this code to a route.ts file.
Since You're using it inside useEffect, It'll directly expose the secrets to the user.
Instead, create a Api Route and use fetch api to get the data to client side(if needed)
